# Error in Sonar while executing Findbug rules

Tags: sonarqube, findbugs

I'm getting following error after configuring my sonar project with findbugs. Please help me out.

```
BUILD FAILED
17-May-2013 11:18:15    /home/build/bamboo-home/xml-data/build-dir/EZIO-EMA-JOB1/build.xml:247: org.sonar.api.utils.SonarException: Can not execute Findbugs
17-May-2013 11:18:15            at org.sonar.plugins.findbugs.FindbugsExecutor.execute(FindbugsExecutor.java:120)
17-May-2013 11:18:15            at org.sonar.plugins.findbugs.FindbugsSensor.analyse(FindbugsSensor.java:58)
17-May-2013 11:18:15            at org.sonar.batch.phases.SensorsExecutor.execute(SensorsExecutor.java:64)
17-May-2013 11:18:15            at org.sonar.batch.phases.Phases.execute(Phases.java:93)
17-May-2013 11:18:15            at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.ProjectModule.doStart(ProjectModule.java:143)
17-May-2013 11:18:15            at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.Module.start(Module.java:89)
17-May-2013 11:18:15            at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.BatchModule.analyze(BatchModule.java:110)
17-May-2013 11:18:15            at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.BatchModule.doStart(BatchModule.java:100)
17-May-2013 11:18:15            at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.Module.start(Module.java:89)
17-May-2013 11:18:15            at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.BootstrapModule.doStart(BootstrapModule.java:96)
17-May-2013 11:18:15            at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.Module.start(Module.java:89)
17-May-2013 11:18:15            at org.sonar.batch.Batch.execute(Batch.java:74)
17-May-2013 11:18:15            at org.sonar.ant.Launcher.execute(Launcher.java:70)
17-May-2013 11:18:15            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
17-May-2013 11:18:15            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
17-May-2013 11:18:15            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
17-May-2013 11:18:15            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
17-May-2013 11:18:15            at org.sonar.ant.SonarTask.delegateExecution(SonarTask.java:202)
17-May-2013 11:18:15            at org.sonar.ant.SonarTask.execute(SonarTask.java:186)
17-May-2013 11:18:15            at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
17-May-2013 11:18:15            at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
17-May-2013 11:18:15            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
17-May-2013 11:18:15            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
17-May-2013 11:18:15            at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
17-May-2013 11:18:15            at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
17-May-2013 11:18:15            at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:390)
17-May-2013 11:18:15            at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:411)
17-May-2013 11:18:15            at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1360)
17-May-2013 11:18:15            at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1329)
17-May-2013 11:18:15            at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
17-May-2013 11:18:15            at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1212)
17-May-2013 11:18:15            at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:801)
17-May-2013 11:18:15            at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:218)
17-May-2013 11:18:15            at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:280)
17-May-2013 11:18:15            at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:109)
17-May-2013 11:18:15    Caused by: org.sonar.api.utils.SonarException: Findbugs needs sources to be compiled. Please build project before executing sonar and check the location of compiled classes.
17-May-2013 11:18:15            at org.sonar.plugins.findbugs.FindbugsConfiguration.getFindbugsProject(FindbugsConfiguration.java:66)
17-May-2013 11:18:15            at org.sonar.plugins.findbugs.FindbugsExecutor.execute(FindbugsExecutor.java:74)
17-May-2013 11:18:15            ... 34 more
```

Comment: Welcome at SO! If you provide some more information help would be easier, e.g. some information about the Sonar version and about the Java version of your project. Also, what do you mean with _configuring my sonar project with findbugs_?

Comment: @AmitKumar, please would you accept the correct answer? It's a lot easier for other people who have the same problem to see what works if you have indicated which solution worked (for me, and yvolk by the looks of it, the answer from Paulo was exactly what I needed)

Answer (score 15):

The Exception message is clear about the *problem*, but not about the *solution*, which is:
at the same place where you defined the `sonar.sources` property, add a `sonar.binaries` property that points to the location of the compiled code. For example, in a maven project you would typically have `sonar.binaries=target/classes`.

Comment: Thank you, I changed sonar.binaries to bin/classes (in my case, for Android) and it worked!

Answer (score 5):

Include the below lines in the jenkins job configuration under execute SonarQube Scanner:

sonar.java.binaries=${workspace}/target/classes/

sonar.binaries=${workspace}/target/classes/

Comment: @melhior Welcome!

Answer (score 3):

The issue is pretty clear:

```
Caused by: org.sonar.api.utils.SonarException: Findbugs needs sources to be compiled. Please build project before executing sonar and check the location of compiled classes.
```

Indeed FindBugs needs bytecode to look for violations.

Comment: we are using ant to build project and compiled classes are in bin folder do I need to put some extra tags in build.xml to make it work. Please guide me. Thanks

Comment: we are using sonar version 2.11 and jdk version as 1.6.0_29. We are using custom quality rule including PMD, checkstyle and findbugs. I upload this file in sonar and link it to particular project.

Comment: Can anybody help me out ??

Comment: @AmitKumar, I guess you haven't correctly set the value of the 'sonar.binaries' property